# Trouble understanding datasheet of LR645

Tags: schematic

I don't understand this schematic. Is the ground on the secondary of the transformer the same as the one on the primary? If so, what is the point doing it, since the isolation would be lost?

How should I use this component?

[image]

Comment: The transformer has 2 independent secondaries. One is only used to 'self-power' the SMPS circuit. The 'main' output secondary is not connected to the input.

Comment: Looks like a strange drawing with the aux winding drawn on the secondary side. Your 5 V output is however still isolated.

Comment: @winny Inputs on the left, outputs on the right? I'm not sure this transformer diagram is meant to show isolation strengths.

Comment: @Neil_UK It's electrically correct, but I draw my primary side grounded windings on the left hand side.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the ground on the secondary of the transformer the same as the one on the primary?

It's one of the secondaries, and it's generally called "auxiliary winding". The aux winding which outputs `VAUX` in the diagram is there to generate supply for the controller IC (self supply). That's why the grounds are connected. The main output, 5V, is still isolated so the isolation will not be lost.

> what is the point doing it

Once the circuit is first powered up there's no switching, and no output voltages present. The flyback controller IC (PWM IC in the diagram) takes its supply input from the LR645 which is a HV linear regulator, and initiates the switching. After a few cycles the outputs will be generated properly, then the PWM IC will get its supply from the VAUX winding.

Auxiliary windings are not well regulated but they are not required to be. The power they deliver is really low – just to power the IC and, if present, provide the gate drive power for the external MOSFET(s).

---

The diagram appears to be showing a flyback regulator as an example but even the winding dots are not present.